# How can I autolaunch an specific folder at start?

Tags: 14.04

I have this folder where is contained some final user files, computer won't be used for anything else but execute those music/video files so I want to auto-launch this folder at start so the user can only execute the files. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Open the dash, type in 'startup applications' and run it. Add a new startup app entry with the command `nautilus /path/to/desired/folder`.